# Spring Boot - When I call API, its gives 404 error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application. When I deploy the jar file in embedded tomcat and called the test API it gives 404 error. May I know why it is giving the error?

**Main class**

```
package com.telematics.fleet;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.telematics.fleet.controller", "com.telematics.fleet.repository",
        "com.telematics.fleet.service","com.telematics.fleet.utility"})
public class TelematicsFleetApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TelematicsFleetApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.telematics.fleet.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class FleetAppController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test()
    {
        System.out.println("Called test API");
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

**Console**

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/dell/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/dell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\dell\.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/dell/.m2/repository/com/mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2/mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar
08:22:29.726 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
08:22:29.738 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
08:22:29.739 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Malya/Git_Homes/telematics-fleet/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-22 08:22:31.881  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.fleet.TelematicsFleetApplication     : Starting TelematicsFleetApplication on admin with PID 252 (C:\Malya\Git_Homes\telematics-fleet\target\classes started by dell in C:\Malya\Git_Homes\telematics-fleet)
2018-03-22 08:22:31.889  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.fleet.TelematicsFleetApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-22 08:22:32.280  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@795b4bba: startup date [Thu Mar 22 08:22:32 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-22 08:22:47.336  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c439cf8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-22 08:22:51.865  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-22 08:22:52.015  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-03-22 08:22:52.016  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-03-22 08:22:52.076  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.3\ARM GCC\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.3\eclipse\jre\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\modeltech64_10.2c\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\myrWork\ztex-160513\sp3anTest\aes220_win_files_160502-1\aes220_win_files\DLL;C:\myrWork\ztex-160513\sp3anTest\aes220_win_files_160502-1\aes220_win_files\libs\MS32;C:\myrWork\eMMCModel\ss_emmc\eMMC_vip\sdio\rlm\win_64;C:\workspace\eMMCModel\ss_emmc\eMMC_vip\sdio\sv\examples\sim;C:\Malya\tool\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.2.RELEASE;;.]
2018-03-22 08:22:52.790  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-03-22 08:22:52.791  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 20525 ms
2018-03-22 08:23:00.377  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-03-22 08:23:00.407  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-22 08:23:00.408  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-22 08:23:00.409  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-22 08:23:00.410  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-22 08:23:00.411  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-22 08:23:00.412  INFO 252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-22 08:23:01.619  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-03-22 08:23:03.674  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-03-22 08:23:04.327  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-22 08:23:04.469  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-03-22 08:23:05.269  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2018-03-22 08:23:05.284  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-03-22 08:23:05.721  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-03-22 08:23:08.342  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-03-22 08:23:16.185  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-22 08:23:34.747  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@795b4bba: startup date [Thu Mar 22 08:22:32 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-22 08:23:36.160  WARN 252 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-03-22 08:23:37.239  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/app/test],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.telematics.fleet.controller.FleetAppController.test()
2018-03-22 08:23:37.380  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-22 08:23:37.383  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-03-22 08:23:38.325  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-22 08:23:38.326  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-22 08:23:39.279  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-22 08:23:40.156  WARN 252 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2018-03-22 08:23:46.453  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2018-03-22 08:23:46.581  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2018-03-22 08:23:46.582  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.0 created.
2018-03-22 08:23:46.588  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore             : RAMJobStore initialized.
2018-03-22 08:23:46.593  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.0) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2018-03-22 08:23:46.595  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2018-03-22 08:23:46.595  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.0
2018-03-22 08:23:46.596  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory@629a27c7
2018-03-22 08:23:47.067  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-03-22 08:23:47.271  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-22 08:23:47.274  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-22 08:23:47.279  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-03-22 08:23:48.079  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-03-22 08:23:48.086  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-03-22 08:23:48.130  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-03-22 08:23:48.207  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-03-22 08:23:48.208  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2018-03-22 08:23:48.209  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2018-03-22 08:23:48.464  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-03-22 08:23:48.488  INFO 252 --- [  restartedMain] c.t.fleet.TelematicsFleetApplication     : Started TelematicsFleetApplication in 78.687 seconds (JVM running for 81.635)
2018-03-22 08:24:55.653  INFO 252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-22 08:24:55.654  INFO 252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-22 08:24:55.755  INFO 252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 101 ms
```

**POSTMAN Response**

```
    {
    "timestamp": "2018-03-22T03:06:40.138+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/telematics-fleet/app/test"
}
```

**Properties file**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

In the console server is running fine but i am getting 404 error when trying to access the api's

Comment: What is the port you are using ?

Comment: I don't see `/telematics-fleet` in your resource mapping?

Comment: what is complete URL you trying to hit?

Comment: +1 for this question just for the formatting and code/output examples. Well formatted and detailed. Cheers!

Comment: At first, I am new to spring boot application.  Project name - telematics-fleet and I assume that default port is 8080. This is the URL am hitting on postman - http://localhost:8080/telematics-fleet/app/test @PrabinPaudel

Comment: http://localhost:8080/telematics-fleet/app/test  @Adi

Comment: The project name is telematics-fleet @PankajGadge

Answer (score 2):

There are two important points to keep in mind while deploying a SpringBoot application to a container :

1.**Starting point of application**: If you are deploying a `SprinBoot` application to any `servlet container`(like `Tomcat`) your starter class must **extend**  [SpringBootServletInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html), so that the container can find the starting point of your application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TelematicsFleetApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TelematicsFleetApplication .class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TelematicsFleetApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

2. After successful deployment on `Tomcat` you should prefix your application name before all resource URLs.

Example : `localhost:8080/Application_Name/app/test`

**Extra tip**: After `Spring 4.3` you can replace `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` by  [@GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)

Example : `@Getmapping("/test")`

Comment: O Lord! Accept my sincere greetings. You have saved our life with your gracious knowledge..

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change your controller to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/telematics-fleet/app")
public class FleetAppController 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test()
    {
        System.out.println("Called test API");
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

The current call does not point to correct resource.

Note the log states that your server was started and pointing to `/` as root and not `/telematics-fleet`.

The other thing you could do is keep your controller as it is and add a new property in `application.properties` as:
`server.contextPath=/telematics-fleet`

Answer (score 1):

Your postman requesting the path---   `"path": "/telematics-fleet/app/test"` but your controller the path should be `"path": "/app/test"` . So there is a missmatch.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing context

```
 http://localhost:8080/app/test
```

If you running it using spring boot plugin, and haven't configured context in meta file, spring boot run on default context

Answer (score 1):

The project name is not automatically added to the context path in Spring Boot, it is `/` by default. If you do want to add it, set the following in your .properties file:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/telematics-fleet
```

Or for pre-2.0 versions of Spring Boot:

```
server.contextPath=/telematics-fleet
```

If not, then just remove that part from your request, hitting `/app/test` directly.

Comment: server.contextPath is now depricated, use server.servlet.contextPath

Answer (score 1):

In my project, it was because of the missing dependency in the pom.

> spring-boot-starter-web

Look for `Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]` in the logs, if it is not there, it means the required dependencies are missing

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. For me, the project name in Eclipse was different from the one that was mentioned in the application.properties.

renaming the eclipse project to the same as the one in application.properties solved the issue

Comment: do you mean `spring.application.name`property ?